# htaccess RewriteRule for folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a bunch of rewrite rules I would like to implement. I would like to redirect anything that has /blog/tag/... to my root url.

For example, all of these:

```
blog/tag/button-sets/
blog/tag/icons/
blog/tag/order-now/
blog/tag/body-attributes/
```

Would simply route to: www.url.com

I can do it on a case-by-case basis like below, but would like to redirect a bunch with 1 rule. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^url\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.url\.com$
RewriteRule ^blog\/tag\/button\-sets\/?(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.url\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you just remove the button-sets part of your rule like so

```
RewriteRule ^blog\/tag\/?(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.url\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

Havent tested it but should be OK?

Comment: This seems to be stripping www.url.com/blog/tag/button-sets/ to just www.url.com/button-sets/ . But I want it to just redirect to www.url.com.

Comment: Very nice. So simple. Thanks Feras and Stephan!

Answer (score 0):

In stead make it such that it captures everything after the second / after blog/tag/(ANYTHING)/(CAPTURE) which will redirect to www.url.com/CAPTURE

```
RewriteRule ^blog\/tag\/.*\/?(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.url\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: If you are wanting to redirect EVERYTHING in the blog/tag/* then just do what @Feras said in the other answer as that'd be better.

Comment: Edited it to do that.